# login_throttling is ignored if correct username/password

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-ratelimiter

I have added [login throttling](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-2-login-throttling) to my symfony app.
If I try to log in 5 times in a row in the same minute with invalid credentials I have a `TooManyLoginAttemptsAuthenticationException` in the `onAuthenticationFailure` method of my authentificator, so far so good.

But if I try to login with correct credentials in the same minute after the `TooManyLoginAttemptsAuthenticationException` I was expecting to have the same error but I'm actually successfully logged in.

Am I missing Something ?

My security.yaml :

```
security:
enable_authenticator_manager: true
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    ldap:
        id: App\Security\LdapUserProvider
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    app_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\Utilisateur
            property: nni
encoders:
    App\Entity\Utilisateur:
        algorithm: 'auto'


role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

access_control:
    - { path: ^/get_team_email$, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
    - { path: ^/login$, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
    - { path: ^/login_check$, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
    - { path: ^, roles: ROLE_USER}

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        security: true
        provider: '%connexion_provider%'
        entry_point: App\Security\LdapFormAuthenticator
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            success_handler: app.logout.success.handler
        # configuring the maximum login attempts (per minute)
        login_throttling:
            max_attempts: 3
        # activate different ways to authenticate
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
        # switch_user: true
        guard:
            authenticators:
            - App\Security\LdapFormAuthenticator
        form_login:
            use_forward: true
            login_path: login
            check_path: login
```

Comment: Are you meaning : if you try to login AGAIN with correct credentials? Could you please forward us the content of your `config/packages/rate_limiter.yaml` file?

Comment: yes that's what I mean. I expected to be rejected even with correct credential if flagged after too many attempt.

Comment: I don't have a rate_limiter.yaml, I followed the instructions here https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-2-login-throttling and here https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/authenticator_manager.html
I have added my security.yaml to the question.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [source code of the throttling handler](https://github.com/wouterj/symfony/blob/5.3/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/EventListener/LoginThrottlingListener.php), the limiter is reset on successful logins. It solely kicks in on three succeeding **failing** login attempts (where that 3 has been defined in your own configuration)

Comment: "the limiter is reset on successful logins" => Doesn't that kill the purpose of the whole thing since it simply replace the "invalid credential" error with a "too many attempt" error ? It would still be possible to try different common password until I'm logged in

Comment: Does it? When you use **valid** credentials, why should it block you if you use these valid credentials multiple times?

Comment: Also, if you disagree with the way this works, you need to open an issue in Symfony's issue tracker

Comment: I expected to be blocked with correct credential AFTER multiple failed attempt (all during the same minute), not multiple successful attempt, but may be I'm wrong

Comment: My opinion is that it could be a good issue with a configuration to select if you want that correct credentials still failed after multiple failed attempts or if you want to allow access. Il will publish an issue and certainly a PR, because I need it in a project.